# Should CSRF token without session cookie work?

Tags: web-application, xss, csrf

Let's say that the website example.com has CSRF protection.
They send a CSRF token in a custom header and in hidden input fields.

For example to add a new folder, your http request needs to contain CSRF token.
What I've observed is that if you make the same request, with CSRF token but withou a session cookie it still works.

Should it works that way, that I can create a folder without session cookie, but solely with CSRF token?

Comment: Welcome to infosec.se. Any chance you could edit your question and reword it to make it a bit clearer what you're asking?

Comment: Absolutely. give me 2 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, no.

CSRF protection and session authentication are typically supposed to be separate concepts entirely. The responsibility of a CSRF token is *supposed* to be a one-time key for a request - nothing more, while a session ID or session token is *supposed* to merely identify a user that has permission to perform the action in the first place.

You should have both in place unless the CSRF token holds both responsibilities somehow (which honestly, would indicate someone tried to be too clever with their security design, and failed).

Answer (score 1):

An interesting one. If the CSRF token identifies the user as well, then I can't see it being a vulnerability in itself. Some systems can work without cookies (although you mention this one is designed to work *with* cookies) and can pass around an auth token in a hidden form field that is used as both a session identifier and an anti-CSRF token.

In your case, as the system does use cookies, it appears to be an authorisation flaw.

You should try some further tests to find out if this is a vulnerability:

- Try issuing the request without the cookie after the "active session" would have normally timed out.
- Try creating two sessions and find out if the CSRF token from one session can be used in the other.
- The creating two sessions under different user accounts and find out if the token from one user can be used in the other. If successful find out which user was associated to the request.
- Try an invalid CSRF token.
- Try a missing CSRF token.

Note for creating two sessions you would need a separate browser or you could create one in private/incognito mode.

By "active session" I am referring to a current short-term session on the website (e.g. one with a sliding expiration of 15-30 minutes or so). For sites that implement "remember me" functionality this should be implemented by a different mechanism that creates a new "active session" whenever the user returns, and a new CSRF token to go with it (rather than just creating a long active session).

If any of the above are still successful then you have discovered a session management flaw.

Comment: Noone of the bullets you written works.
The concern which I have is - with XSS attack you need to encourage someone to visit your link/website for each attack you want to do. With this kind of issue, you can simply steal CSRF token once, and then do request remotely on behalf of that user. If both session and CSRF token would be verified, then this issue won't exist, as with XSS you can't steal cookie with httponly&secure flags.  Does it make any sense?

Comment: Then it appears that this is not a security flaw. As the CSRF token is private to that session, it seems it is used as an alternative auth mechanism.

Comment: The protection relies on the CSRF token not being stolen - this should not be possible. What is your mechanism for stealing the CSRF token?

Comment: If you find an XSS you can steal CSRF token by pulling it out from DOM. Normally with XSS for each attack you need to ask victim to visit your website with exploit.
With website veryfing only CSRF token, you just grab the token once and then don't ask victim anymore to visit your link. It makes exploitation much more easier, as less Social Engineering is involved, right?

Comment: I follow you now. If you have found an XSS flaw then this is always worse than the CSRF flaw - you can do so much more damage. If you can already inject script into the user's session you can simply add the code to submit the form right there and then (including CSRF token and the auth cookie as the user is already logged in). No need for them to visit the attacker's website as the attacker already has control.

Comment: Yes, but in my scenario I consider reflected XSS so each exploitation requires user's interaction. Having CSRF token I can make as many request as I want, as long as session is valid. So if I want to check emails of my victim, I would need to ask him each day to visit my link with exploit. 
Without session validation, I can do it myself using that CSRF token.
Does it make sense now?

Comment: I am not considering timeouted session. I am saying that I can use CSRF token as long as session is live, which for most websites is few days, or with 'remember me' much longer.

Comment: You said that none of those work. Therefore the site is safe because the request will not work after the session expiry (first bullet).

Comment: CSRF tokens should be tied to _current_ session - i.e. the one that expires in the next 20 minutes or so on a sliding expiration. "Remember me" functionality should be a different mechanism that creates a _current_ session along with new CSRF tokens.

Comment: That's the thing. With CSRF token you can check someone's emails until session expiry. If cookies would be checked with CSRF token, then you would need to ask victim to go to your exploit, each day.

Comment: Then you have found a session management flaw - sessions do not expire properly.

Comment: Hmm. so what is proposed session expiration time? Around 20 minutes?

Comment: Bullet "Try creating two sessions and find out if the CSRF token from one session can be used in the other."
 works, as I said before - it doesn't verify session, so it doesn't matter from which session token it is. It is for one user so it works. How is this a issue?

Comment: Yes, around 20 for an active session. It would only be an issue if the action was under the authorisation of the auth cookie rather than the token because it would mean any CSRF token could be used to ride sessions.

Answer (score 0):

**Scenario 1:** If the token is generated using a cryptographically secure PRNG, a basic attack like you describe is not possible including if session token isn't sent through that particular request - it don't work as well - so overall this does not work.

**Scenario 2:** However, if the tokens your application generates are not strong and have bypasses around, this should work but would fail if session tokens doesn't go with it - again as indicated by @AgmLauncher in his answer.

**Scenario 3**:  CSRF token fails + you have the session token, say via XSS - it works.